# Jquery, ajax() and each(), how to wait untill all info is really loaded?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, each

I have a function using $.ajax() to get values from an XML file, when the info is loaded and success event is fired, I use $(xml).find('').each(function(){}); to populate some vars...

```
function getData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'info.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml)
        {
            $(xml).find('DATAS').each(function()
            {
                date = new Date($(this).attr('DATE'));
                alert(date);
            })
                    //Here I have a bigger find/each that should take more time 
        },
            error: function()
            {
                    return false;
            }

    }); 
}
```

In this case, when I trigger the function from the document ready function, the alert shows the right data, but If I remove the alert from the function and try this instead, date wont be defined yet:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if(getData() != false)
{
    alert(date);

    }
});
```

I guess in this case the data is not ready yet?
Is there a way to keep control on when the whole each() traversing is finished and ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because AJAX is asynchronous, meaning that the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call doesn't finish until after the `if()` completes...the `alert()` in the way just gives it time to complete.  You should kick off any operation that needs to use the data from inside the `success` callback, when it runs the data is then available.  Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  getDataAndDoSomething();
  //other ready stuff...
});
function getDataAndDoSomething() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : 'info.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('DATAS').each(function() {
            date = new Date($(this).attr('DATE'));
            alert(date);
        })
        //Do the other stuff depending on the date data
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Going to check this out, about the ajax: async I have already tried in the past and it can really frozen the browser.

Answer (score 5):

`.ajax()` launches an asynchronous request, which means that `getData()` will return immediately. You have to do all kind of acting on the returned data within your success handler or, set the `.ajax` request to syncronous by adding

```
$.ajax({
   async: false   
});
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against `async: false` whenever possible, this needlessly locks up the user's browser.

Comment: @Nick: agreed 100%, but putting this into the answer might make things better to understand.